# How to find outliers in a given dataset using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, statistics, linear-regression, outliers

**coordinates = [(259, 168), (62, 133), (143, 163), (174, 270), (321, 385)]**

**slope = 0.76083799

intercept = 77.87127406**

[image]

The coordinate with the brown marker is a potential outlier for me and thus need to be removed. As of now i am ***trying*** to use the student residual and jackknife residual to remove these outliers. However i am not able to calculate these residuals given the dataset that i have.

It would be really helpful if you people can help me in finding the residuals and how to do it as well in the above dataset.

**CODE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coordinates = [(259, 168), (62, 133), (143, 163), (174, 270), (321, 385)]

x=[x1[0] for x1 in coordinates]
y=[x1[1] for x1 in coordinates]

for x1,y1 in coordinates:
   plt.plot(x1,y1,marker="o",color="brown")
plt.show()

# using numpy polyfit method to find regression line slope and intercept 
z = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
print(z)
slope = z[0]
intercept =z[1]

newx = np.linspace(62,321,200)
newy = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,y, 'o', newx, newy(newx),color="black")
# plt.plot()
plt.plot(259,168,marker="o",color="brown")
plt.show()

#TODO
#remove the outliers and then display
```

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: @OscarSmith i have added the code

Answer (score 1):

x and y are placed into `np.ndarrays` at the start.

Input:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coordinates = [(259, 168), (62, 133), (143, 163), (174, 270), (321, 385)]

x=np.array([x1[0] for x1 in coordinates]) #Placed into array
y=np.array([x1[1] for x1 in coordinates]) #Placed into array

for x1,y1 in coordinates:
   plt.plot(x1,y1,marker="o",color="brown")
plt.show()

# using numpy polyfit method to find regression line slope and intercept 
z = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
print(z)
slope = z[0]
intercept =z[1]

newx = np.linspace(62,321,200)
newy = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,y, 'o', newx, newy(newx),color="black")
# plt.plot()
plt.plot(259,168,marker="o",color="brown")
plt.show()
```

Additional code:

```
print("old y: " + repr(y)) #Display original array of y values
print("old x: " + repr(x)) 
residual_array = abs(y - (intercept + slope * x)) #Create an array of residuals
max_accept_deviation = 100 #An arbitrary value of "acceptable deviation"
mask = residual_array >= max_accept_deviation #Create an array of TRUE/FALSE values. TRUE where residual array is larger than deviation
rows_to_del = tuple(te for te in np.where(mask)[0]) #np.where converts the mask to a list of row numbers which is converted to a tuple
cleaned_y = np.delete(y,rows_to_del) #np.delete deletes all row numbers in the earlier tuple
cleaned_x = np.delete(x,rows_to_del)
print("new y: " + repr(cleaned_y)) #Print the cleaned values
print("new x: " + repr(cleaned_x))
```

Output:

```
[  0.76083799  77.87127406]
old y: array([168, 133, 163, 270, 385])
old x: array([259,  62, 143, 174, 321])
new y: array([133, 163, 270, 385])
new x: array([ 62, 143, 174, 321])
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, can you please explain a bit as what has been done in the code.

Comment: Alright, i added comments to the additional code! Just let me know if theres anything you're not sure about!